# error :data:text/html,chromewebdata - aspnetboilerplate

Tags: google-chrome, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using `Abp.1.4.2.0 version`. When I click on "Login as this user" or "Login as this tenant", while URL redirecting an error

> data:text/html,chromewebdata

occurred as shown in screenshot. This error only exist in chrome browser.

[Here's the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpJ0m.png)

Could someone please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try disabling  Visual Studio client side debugging.

[image]